# How to run a bash script in a daily basis on my remote server?

Tags: linux, webserver, bash-scripting

I have code need to be run in daily basis at my ubuntu remote server. How can I set it to go as described? Is there any console too to help me ? And this code should be activated itself as the machine rebooted.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the `cron` service for this. A quick guide:

1. Log in to the server
2. Switch to the user as which you want to run the program/script as
3. Run the command `crontab -e`
4. You now get an editor. At the end of the line, add:

`0 3 * * * /path/to/program_or_script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1`

5. Save the file

This will run the command every day at 03:00. You can adjust the times accordingly. The `>/dev/null 2>&1` will discard any output from the command.

You could replace the /path/to/program_or_script.sh by a one-liner, or you could put your 'code' in a small shell script (start the file with `#!/bin/bash` and add the 'code' on a new line).

Keep in mind that most cron environments don't have a full shell environment, so you would have to set environment variables or even PATH settings manually (`PATH=/usr/bin:/bin` etc.)

Comment: [Here is another good answer if more help is needed.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)